# they had been able to say

Tags: grammar

Which is right, "had been" or "were"? Are both acceptable?

> By the time the kids left preschool, they **had been** able to say what was on their minds.
>
> By the time the kids left preschool, they **were** able to say what was on their minds.

Comment: Do you mean that they were articulate enough to express their thoughts in words? If so, use _were able_. The past perfect _had been able_ sounds as if you were referring to a particular incident in the past when they had spoken about their feelings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [had been or were: By the time I arrived home, three police cars with lights going had been at my condo](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535223/had-been-or-were-by-the-time-i-arrived-home-three-police-cars-with-lights-goin)